# Encode an azimuthal equidistant projection in NetCDF conversion

Tags: python, gdal, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I'm trying to do Azimuthal Equidistant in CF-compliant NetCDF, but I didn't get the correct projection.
If you compare the first two information (gdalinfo) you see there is no `AUTHORITY` and also `PROJCS`, `GEOGCS`, `DATUM`, `SPHEROID` are unknown.

I followed this link to set the set the projection: 
[Mapping from CF Grid Mapping Attributes to CRS WKT Elements](https://github.com/cf-convention/cf-conventions/wiki/Mapping-from-CF-Grid-Mapping-Attributes-to-CRS-WKT-Elements)

This is the original projection which I want to save it to NetCDF.

```
Size is 8000, 8000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Azimuthal_Equidistant",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Azimuthal_Equidistant"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",53],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",24],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",5837287.81977],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",2121415.69617],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (4800000.000000000000000,1800000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (75.000000000000000,-75.000000000000000)
```

and this is what I got:

```
Size is 8000, 8000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unknown",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["Spheroid",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Azimuthal_Equidistant"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",53],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",24],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",5837287.81977],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",2121415.69617]]
Origin = (4799602.500000000000000,1800037.500000000000000)
Pixel Size = (75.000000000000000,-75.000000000000000)
```

here is the code that I extracted the projection:

```
# Extract Projection info from tiff
ds = gdal.Open('sample.tiff')
prj = ds.GetProjection()
srs = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)


# Create container variable for CRS
crso = nco.createVariable('crs', 'i4')
crso.grid_mapping_name = 'azimuthal_equidistant'
crso.projected_crs_name = srs.GetAttrValue('PROJCS')
crso.geographic_crs_name = srs.GetAttrValue('GEOGCS')
crso.horizontal_datum_name = srs.GetAttrValue('DATUM')
crso.latitude_of_projection_origin = srs.GetProjParm('latitude_of_center')
crso.longitude_of_projection_origin = srs.GetProjParm('longitude_of_center')
crso.false_easting = srs.GetProjParm('false_easting')
crso.false_northing = srs.GetProjParm('false_northing')
crso.longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0.0
crso.semi_major_axis = 6378137.0
crso.inverse_flattening = 298.257223563
```

Does someone know how to get the correct projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution (maybe this will help someone), I have to write the Spatial reference into the CRS variable, then netcdf can recognize all projection info which is defined.

```
crso.spatial_ref = str(srs)
```

str(srs) gives me:

```
 crs#spatial_ref=PROJCS["Azimuthal_Equidistant",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Azimuthal_Equidistant"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",53],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",24],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",5837287.81977],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",2121415.69617],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```